# Regex in Notepad++ to grab specific repetitive events in logs

Tags: regex

I have the following log sample from an application:

```
@20:20:51.8200 [0] 8.1.104.23 distribute_event: message EventRinging
    AttributeUserData   [634] 00 18 00 00..
        'RTargetObjectSelected' '?VAG_EMERGENCIA2:'
20:20:53.821: $+SIP:CTI:HA_SEND_SYNC_MESSAGE:39982499:0
20:20:54.821: $+SIP:CTI:HA_SEND_SYNC_MESSAGE:39982499:0
20:20:54.821 Int 04544 Interaction message "EventRinging" generated
@20:21:51.8200 [0] 8.1.104.23 distribute_event: message EventRinging
    AttributeUserData   [634] 00 18 00 00..
        'RTargetObjectSelected' '?VAG_EMERGENCIA1:'
20:20:54.821 Int 04544 Interaction message "EventRinging" generated
@20:21:51.8200 [0] 8.1.104.23 distribute_event: message EventRinging
    AttributeUserData   [634] 00 18 00 00..
        'RTargetObjectSelected' '?VAG_AGENCIA1:'
20:20:54.821 Int 04544 Interaction message "EventRinging" generated
20:23:51.821: $+SIP:CTI:HA_SEND_SYNC_MESSAGE:39982499:0
20:24:51.821: $+SIP:CTI:HA_SEND_SYNC_MESSAGE:39982499:0
@20:25:51.8200 [0] 8.1.104.23 distribute_event: message EventRinging
    AttributeUserData   [634] 00 18 00 00..
        'RTargetObjectSelected' '?VAG_EMERGENCIA1:'
20:20:54.821 Int 04544 Interaction message "EventRinging" generated 
20:28:51.821: $+SIP:CTI:HA_SEND_SYNC_MESSAGE:39982499:0
@20:29:51.8200 [0] 8.1.104.23 distribute_event: message EventNotRinging
    AttributeUserData   [634] 00 18 00 00..
        'RTargetObjectSelected' '?VAG_EMERGENCIA2:'
20:20:54.821 Int 04544 Interaction message "EventNotRinging" generated
20:30:51.821: $+SIP:CTI:HA_SEND_SYNC_MESSAGE:39982499:0
20:31:51.821: $+SIP:CTI:HA_SEND_SYNC_MESSAGE:39982499:0
20:32:51.821: $+SIP:CTI:HA_SEND_SYNC_MESSAGE:39982499:0
@20:33:51.8200 [0] 8.1.104.23 distribute_event: message EventRinging
    AttributeUserData   [634] 00 18 00 00..
        'RTargetObjectSelected' '?VAG_EMERGENCIA2:'
20:20:54.821 Int 04544 Interaction message "EventRinging" generated
20:34:51.821: $+SIP:CTI:HA_SEND_SYNC_MESSAGE:39982499:0
20:35:51.821: $+SIP:CTI:HA_SEND_SYNC_MESSAGE:39982499:0
20:36:51.821: $+SIP:CTI:HA_SEND_SYNC_MESSAGE:39982499:0
@20:37:51.8200 [0] 8.1.104.23 distribute_event: message EventNotRinging
    AttributeUserData   [634] 00 18 00 00..
        'RTargetObjectSelected' '?VAG_EMERGENCIA1:'
20:20:54.821 Int 04544 Interaction message "EventRinging" generated
20:38:51.821: $+SIP:CTI:HA_SEND_SYNC_MESSAGE:39982499:0
20:39:51.821: $+SIP:CTI:HA_SEND_SYNC_MESSAGE:39982499:0
@20:40:51.8200 [0] 8.1.104.23 distribute_event: message EventRinging
    AttributeUserData   [634] 00 18 00 00..
        'RTargetObjectSelected' '?VAG_EMERGENCIA2:'
20:20:54.821 Int 04544 Interaction message "EventNotRinging" generated
20:41:51.821: $+SIP:CTI:HA_SEND_SYNC_MESSAGE:39982499:0
@20:42:51.8200 [0] 8.1.104.23 distribute_event: message EventNotRinging
    AttributeUserData   [634] 00 18 00 00..
        'RTargetObjectSelected' '?VAG_EMERGENCIA1:'
20:20:54.821 Int 04544 Interaction message "EventNotRinging" generated
20:42:51.821: $+SIP:CTI:HA_SEND_SYNC_MESSAGE:39982499:0
```

What I am trying to do is to get all EventRinging events with attribute RTargetObjectSelected = VAG_EMERGENCIA2

I can grab all the EventRinging Events with this RegEx:

```
(distribute_event: message EventRinging).*?(EventRinging..generated)
```

Then I tried adding RTargetObjectSelected = VAG_EMERGENCIA2 to the logic

```
(distribute_event: message EventRinging).*?(RTargetObjectSelected.\t..VAG_EMERGENCIA2).*?(EventRinging..generated)
```

Yes, I know maybe the expression could be better formatted but I am out of ideas.

With this second approach it fails as would also catch only two occurrences

```
@20:20:51.8200 [0] 8.1.104.23 distribute_event: message EventRinging
    AttributeUserData   [634] 00 18 00 00..
        'RTargetObjectSelected' '?VAG_EMERGENCIA2:'
20:20:53.821: $+SIP:CTI:HA_SEND_SYNC_MESSAGE:39982499:0
20:20:54.821: $+SIP:CTI:HA_SEND_SYNC_MESSAGE:39982499:0
20:20:54.821 Int 04544 Interaction message "EventRinging" generated
```

But second one will select as follows:

[image]

Any idea on how can I fine tune this?

This is my Notepad search option configured as
[image]

Thanks in advance

Please consider the disordered time stamps are intended as log is actually quite bigger than this but made a small "lab" with this one and fits my testing needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use a pattern to match the line that starts with an @ and digit and has `distribute_event: message EventRinging` at the end of the string.

Then continue matching all lines that do not start with @ and a digit and match the line the contains `RTargetObjectSelected' '?VAG_EMERGENCIA2`

```
^@\d.*distribute_event: message EventRinging(?:\R(?!\d).*)*\R.*RTargetObjectSelected'\h+'\?VAG_EMERGENCIA2.*
```

The pattern in parts:

- `^` Start of string
- `@\d` Match @ and a digit
- `.*distribute_event: message EventRinging` Match the whole line and `distribute_event: message EventRinging` at the end
- `(?:\R(?!\d).*)*` Optionally repeat all lines that do not start with a digit, where `(?!` is a negative lookahead and `\R` matches any unicode newline sequence
- `\R.*RTargetObjectSelected` Match a newline, the whole line till `RTargetObjectSelected`
- `'\h+'\?` Match `'` 1+ horizontal whitespace chars and then `'?`
- `VAG_EMERGENCIA2.*` Match `VAG_EMERGENCIA2` and the rest of the line

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LbqP7E/1).

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks a lot! Please could you detail each parameter you used?

Comment: @JorgeCornejoBellido You are welcome, I have added a breakdown of the separate parts in the pattern.

Comment: Agains, thanks! This will help me to reduce hours of work! Amazing regex knowledge